# R: Rename some variables in list of dataframes to match others

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I have a list of data frames with inconsistent but overlapping variables. Some of the shared variables have similar but not identical names. I would like to conditionally rename the variable so that it is consistent across datasets. The way to do this one at a time would be

```
library(tidyverse)
df_1 <- starwars
df_2 <- starwars %>% rename(haircolor = hair_color)
df_3 <- starwars

df_list <- list(df_1, df_2, df_3)

df_list[[2]] <- df_list[[2]] %>% rename(hair_color = haircolor)
```

But I would like this to be flexible such that I can just feed in a list of any size and it will rename any variable titled `hair_color` as `haircolor`. Is there a way to `purrr::map` over these in a way that renames conditionally on the variable existing? The most basic interpretation would look something like:

```
df_list %>% 
  purrr::map( ~ rename(., hair_color = haircolor))
```

Comment: Do you mean in `df_list` you can various variation of "hair_color" like "harcolor", "harcolor" and you want to rename all of them to "haircolor"  and similarly for other variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can pass this in a `select_helpers` function

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df_list %>% 
  purrr::map( ~  .x %>%
                   rename_at(vars(matches('hair_color')), ~ 'haircolor'))
```

---

Or use an `if/else` condition

```
df_list %>% 
  purrr::map( ~ if('hair_color' %in% names(.)) {
            rename(., haircolor = hair_color)
            } else .)
```

Comment: This is great! For the tidyverse option, is there a way to use `across` rather than the scoped version of `rename`?

Comment: @XÆA-12  With renaming, it is `rename_with` or `rename_at`.  The `across` is used for applying functions within each column where we don't get the column info